# Qt QUrlInfo usage example

Tags: qt, qt4

I see Qt has a nifty class name QUrlInfo.  It has methods/functions that I'd like to use but I'm confused about how to use this class.  The initialization seems very strange and awkward.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurlinfo.html#setLastModified

**For example:**

I'd like to use its method named QUrlInfo::setLastModified so that I can set the lastModified timestamp for a local file. (also on a shared netw file but right now I just want to focus on a local file).

Let's say that the local file is "D:/dir1/dir2/file.txt".

How can I use QUrlInfo when I only have the fullFileName ("D:/dir1/dir2/file.txt") of an item and wish to use QUrlInfo's GET and SET methods?  In particular I'd like an example of how I can create a QUrlInfo object and use its QUrlInfo::setLastModified method.

**Deeper explanation:**

My main source of confusion comes from the fact that its constructor looks like the 
following

```
//Version 1: Problem is you must already have a QUrlInfo object.
QUrlInfo ( const QUrlInfo & ui )

//Version2: Problem is you must already know everything about the file.
//This makes QUrlInfo objects large set of GET methods useless for the most part
//since you must already know all the GET info prior to making a QUrlInfo object.
//Chicken and egg scenario.  I don't see what is point of making a class that gets
//info... but... you must already know all that info to begin with or you can't
// initialize the the class.  
QUrlInfo ( const QString & name, int permissions, const QString & owner, 
const QString & group, qint64 size, const QDateTime & lastModified, 
const QDateTime & lastRead, bool isDir, bool isFile, bool isSymLink, 
bool isWritable, bool isReadable, bool isExecutable )

//Version3: Same problem as in version 2.
QUrlInfo ( const QUrl & url, int permissions, const QString & owner, 
const QString & group, qint64 size, const QDateTime & lastModified, 
const QDateTime & lastRead, bool isDir, bool isFile, bool isSymLink, 
bool isWritable, bool isReadable, bool isExecutable )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs..

> Note that setting values does not affect the underlying resource that the QUrlInfo provides information about; for example if you call setWritable(true) on a read-only resource the only thing changed is the QUrlInfo object, not the resource.

This class is only meant for managing information that you already know about a resource.

There are some attributes that can be set using `QFile` but these are limited and come with warnings in the docs as the behavior is OS dependent. You will likely need to use native APIs to manipulate file attributes reliably.